# How to do POST request with WP REST API v2 to custom table?

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api

I have custom table called `wp_props` and need to make simple search with a couple of params and return json data. I want to use [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) for that, how to use **custom table** with that api as I see only already defined resources (`get_posts`, `users` etc.)? Should I first write php query and then try `register_rest_route` which will use that php file? Is that possible and how to do it?

Thanks.